# Downloaded audio files from Internet in iOS are not playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, download

Well I've read so many similar questions to mine, but I still can not solve the problem.

I'm going to download audio files from Internet and then play them. Using NSURLConnection, I managed to download the file successfully. Here is the code I to download the file.

```
- (IBAction)download:(id)sender 
{
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.dailywav.com/0813/bicycles.wav"]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if (theConnection) {        
    receivedData = [NSMutableData data] ;  
} else {NSLog(@"no connection!");
}
```

Then for saving and playing the file I wrote the following

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

NSLog(@"didfinishloading Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);

NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSLog(@"%@", [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0]);
NSString *documentDirectoryPath = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *folderPath = [documentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFolder/doScience.wav"];
[receivedData writeToFile:folderPath atomically:YES];
NSError *error;
AVPlayer * player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:folderPath]];
if (player == nil) {
    NSLog(@"AudioPlayer did not load properly: %@", [error description]);
} else {
    [player play];
    NSLog(@"playing!");
}
}
```

And here is what I get from console after running

> 2013-08-23 13:57:51.636 Download_2[4461:c07] didfinishloading Received
>   34512 bytes of data 2013-08-23 13:57:51.637 Download_2[4461:c07]
>   /Users/my_name/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/6.1/Applications/88561BAC-66BF-4774-A626-0CEFEC82D63E/Library/Documentation
>   2013-08-23 13:57:51.639 Download_2[4461:c07] playing!

Seems everything is working, but the problem is I can't hear anything when I run the project!

Comment: "I even don't get any error" - you surely don't, if you pass in `nil` for the `error` argument... (that should be `NULL` anyway...)

Comment: Where are you writing the recievedData to filePath directory?

Comment: @Puneet that's right, I just download the data and made a directory, but I didn't put data in the directory.
but how can I put NSMutableData "reciecedData" to NSString "filePath"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I've never made directory "myFolder", also NSDocumentationDirectory should be changed to NSDocumentDirectory to be able to write to. Here is the corrected code

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

NSLog(@"Succeed! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);

NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//NSLog(@"%@", [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0]);
NSString *documentDirectoryPath = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *folderPath = [documentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.wav"];
[receivedData writeToFile:folderPath atomically:YES];
    NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:folderPath];
NSError *error;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:folderPath]) {

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
    player.volume=0.5;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (!error) {
        [player play];
        NSLog(@"File is playing!");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Error in creating audio player:%@",[error description]);
    }
}
else{
    NSLog(@"File doesn't exist");
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is easier way to play remote files - use `AVPlayer` instead of `AVAudioPlayer`. It's also more user-friendly since AVPlayer can play files during download process.

```
- (IBAction)playSound:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.dailywav.com/0813/bicycles.wav"];
    AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

    player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
    [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{

    if (object == player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if ([player status] == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");
        } else if ([player status] == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Ready to Play");
            [player play];
        } else if ([player status] == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");
        }
    }
}
```

You can also find sample project [here](https://github.com/davestitz/iOS-AvPlayer-Demo)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this   ,

```
-(IBAction)download:(id)sender 
{    


NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.dailywav.com/0813/bicycles.wav"]];
NSString *docDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/bicycles.wav", docDirPath ];
[audioData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

NSError *error;
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
if (player == nil) {
    NSLog(@"AudioPlayer did not load properly: %@", [error description]);
} else {
    [player play];
}
}
```

Comment: @Virssu mca I put your code into the project, seems it's playing, but I can't hear anything.
then I put the code in
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection  method, because download is completed there, but I couldn't hear anything again, I can't see what is the problem